# How can I limit git rev-list to a specific branch and remote?

Tags: git

I want to be able to search `git rev-list` for specific remote/branch combinations. I'm confused by the [git rev-list documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) regarding the `--branches` and `--remotes` options, which I think are what I want to use.

For `--remotes`, the documentation says:

> --remotes[=pattern]
>
> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/remotes are listed on the command line as [commit]. If [pattern] is given, limit remote-tracking branches to ones matching given shell glob. If pattern lacks ?, *, or [, /* at the end is implied.

I don't understand what it means when it says they are listed on the command line like "commit".

Part of my confusion is that I'm not sure what format of string `--branches` and `--remotes` searches through, so I am left trying to throw in wildcards in various places to see if it works. I would have assumed that the branches would be like "remotes/remote_name/branch_name" and the remotes would like "remote_name" but when I try to search with that in mind, I don't get the results I expect.

For example, here is the base query that I want to run:

```
 git rev-list --after='timestamp' --author="Name" --format='%h,%aI,%cI'
```

I've used variations of `--branches=*remote_name/branch_name --remotes=remote_name` with various wildcard configurations, but it never works. What I mean by that is, that I know that on certain remote/branch combinations that Commit A exists, but sometimes all branches for a particular remote will find Commit A even if it shouldn't, sometimes no branches on a non-origin remote will return Commit A, even though I know it exists there, etc.

I think if I just better understood how to search with `--branches` and `--remotes` I would be able to piece it together. Maybe `rev-list` is not meant to be searched through with both these options on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks as if `--branches=*branch_name --remotes=*remote_name` works, _but_, only if those branches are checked out, otherwise, `rev-list` doesn't know about them (not in `refs/`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

The solution for searching *both* a remote and branch is to use the following option:

```
git rev-list ... --remotes=*remote_name/branch_name
```

Using both the `--remotes` and `--branches` option here *can* work, but only if you have checked out the branch in question.

**Explanation**

Using `--branches=*branch_name` looks for branches with the given name in `refs/heads`, which is a folder that stores information about your checked out branches. That means it can *only* search git revision history based on branches that you have already checked out.

Using `--remotes=*remote_name` looks for remotes with this name, so long as they have been added to your local list of remotes (`refs/remotes` is a folder that stores information about all your added remotes).

If you use these two options together, `rev-list` can find your remote, but it cannot find your branch *unless you've checked it out*.

However, `refs/remotes` actually stores information about *all* branches on those remotes, so that's all you need to search through, by using `--remotes=*remote_name/branch_name`.

You can see what information you have in `refs` by going to the actual folder in your hidden `.git` folder. From your git folder, simply `cd .git/refs`.

Comment: Beware of finding refs by looking in `.git/refs`, as some refs aren't in there: in particular, any *packed* reference is in `.git/packed-refs` in the current implementation. `git for-each-ref` will let you iterate through all reference names (except the special `HEAD` and `*_HEAD` names) from a script, insulating you from both the current packing scheme and any future changes.

Answer (score 5):

#### TL;DR

`git rev-list` is all about traversing a commit graph (a DAG).  You give it starting points.  `--branches` is one way of giving it various starting points; `--remotes` is another.  Unlike `git log`, which defaults to using `HEAD` as a starting point, you *must* give *some* commit starting point to `git rev-list`.  It then lists *reachable commits:* the names are only relevant in terms of locating the starting points for the graph-walk.

#### Long

In Git, you have to keep in mind what a branch is (or isn't).  Without this concept you'll be led badly astray.  For comparison, let's look first at Mercurial, where *branch* is a more specific thing (although Git's loose and sloppy definition of *branch* is leaking into Mercurial usage these days as well).

In Mercurial, you create a branch using:

```
hg branch <name>
```

and then make commits on it.  Those commits are *on* that branch, forever (well, until / unless they are *stripped*, but ignoring the ability to remove commits, they are there forever).  If commit `C` is on branch `X` is on `X`, and not on any other branch.  Ask which commits are on branch `X` and it will always include `C`.  Makes sense, right?  Commits are stapled permanently to their branch; the branch is the collection of all the commits ever made on that branch.

In Git, this is not the case.  You make commit `C` on branch `X` and it's on branch `X`, but in a few minutes (or days or months), it's *also* on branches `Y` and `Z` and `master`.  Remove branch `X` entirely at this point, and commit `C` is still there, still on branches `Y` and `Z` and `master`.  You can even *move* the name `X` so that commit `C` is *not* on `X` any more, but still is on `master`.

In other words, in Git, commits are *not* stapled to their branch(es).  Whether a commit is in some branch is a dynamic property, that may change in the future.  Commits exist with or without branches containing them.  The *commits* are what matter; branches are just there for puny humans.<sup>1</sup>  But, the commits are permanent (well, mostly) and read-only, frozen forever.  So the *commits* are fixed; it's the *branch names* that move.

With that in mind, let's draw a few graphs.

---

<sup>1</sup>Branch names, or other references, serve several other purposes in Git, but it's best to start with this as your model.  Once you grasp this concept, the rest will fall into place.

---

#### Git commit graphs

Each commit records its immediate predecessor, or *parent*, commit(s).  In the simplest case, one commit has one parent, and the parent of that one commit has one parent, and so on.  Starting at the *end* of the chain, we can easily work backwards:

```
A  <-B  <-C  ...  <-G <-H   <--master
```

The branch *name*, in this case `master`, stores the raw hash ID of the *last* commit that is to be considered part of this branch.  Commit `H` stores another commit hash ID, for its predecessor commit `G`.  `G` stores the hash ID of its parent, and so on, back through commit `B`.  Commit `B` stores `A`'s hash ID, but `A` is the very first commit ever, so it has *no* parent.

(Because commits themselves are fixed, there's no need to draw the internal arrows as arrows any more, which helps with the next step because the arrow-drawing in text is pretty limited.  So from now on I'll use:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

for instance.  The branch-name arrows, however, move a lot, so it's useful to keep them as arrows.)

Adding a *new* commit to a branch, in Git, is a matter of freezing a source snapshot and creating the commit object.  The new commit object records the current commit's hash ID, so that we maintain this backwards chain.  The new commit then gets its own new unique hash ID, and Git writes the new hash ID into the branch name:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

becomes:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

But we can add more branch names.  Before we make another new commit, let's do that: let's make branch name `develop` *also* point to commit `D`:

```
A--B--C--D    <-- master, develop
```

Now Git needs to know *which* branch name to update, so Git attaches the name `HEAD` to one (and only one) branch name:

```
A--B--C--D    <-- master, develop (HEAD)
```

Now when we make a new commit `E`, the branch name that Git updates is no longer `master`, but rather `develop`:

```
A--B--C--D    <-- master
          \
           E   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Commits `E` is now on `develop`.  Commits `A` and `D` are also all on develop *and* are on `master`.  Let's `git checkout master` now and make a new commit `F`:

```
A--B--C--D--F    <-- master (HEAD)
          \
           E   <-- develop
```

Commit `F` is now *only* on `master`, while `E` is *only* on `develop`, and `A-B-C-D` are on both.

If we make a few more commits on develop, we get:

```
A--B--C--D--F    <-- master
          \
           E--G--H   <-- develop
```

(I've left out `HEAD` here since we're about to move it anyway.)

Now let's run `git checkout master && git merge develop`.  This will combine all our `master` changes since the shared commit `D` with all our `develop` changes since the shared commit `D`.  That is, Git will run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-E>   # what happened on master
git diff --find-renmaes <hash-of-D> <hash-of-H>   # what happened on develop
```

Git will combine the two sets of changes, apply them to the snapshot in `D`, and make a new commit `I` that has *two* parents:

```
A--B--C--D--F------I    <-- master (HEAD)
          \       /
           E--G--H   <-- develop
```

Commit `I` reaches back to *both* `H` *and* `F`, and `H` reaches back to `G`, then to `E`, and then the fork we made rejoins in the backwards direction at `D`, which leads to `C` and `B` and finally `A`.  So *all* these commits are now on `master`.  Commits `I` and `F` are *only* on `master`, while `A-B-C-D-E-G-H` are on both branches.

This is what is special about a merge commit.  Now that we have the merge commit, we can *delete* the name `develop`:

```
A--B--C--D--F------I    <-- master (HEAD)
          \       /
           E--G--H
```

The commits all remain on `master`.  The name `develop` no longer exists.  Was it ever even there, or was that a mirage?  Git won't care either way.

#### `git rev-list` and `git log`

Both `git rev-list` and `git log` are concerned with this commit graph.  These two commands are pretty close to each other—in fact, they're built from the same source file, with two different entry points based on whether you ran `git log` or `git rev-list`.  Both will traverse the graph, starting from the end(s) that you specify and working backwards.  While `git log` defaults to showing you each traversed commit, `git rev-list` defaults to just printing their hash IDs.

The other key difference is this `HEAD` notion.  Git wants to keep track of which branch you have checked out, by attaching the name `HEAD` to one branch-name.  The `git log` command will, by default, look up `HEAD` and use that as its (single) starting point; `git rev-list` requires that you give it some starting point(s).

Both of them do this "start from the end and work backwards" thing.  If `master` points to commit `I` as in our example above, and `I` is a merge commit that points back to commits `F` and `H`, both will first show you commit `I` (or its hash ID), then pick one of `F` and `H` to show next.  Then they will show `G` and `E` (and `F` if they haven't yet, somewhere in this mix) and `D` and C`and`B`and`A`, and since`A` has no parent, stop there.

In the end, both will have shown, or listed, every commit, since every commit is reachable from the given starting point, commit `I`.  If you give them a different starting point, such as commit `D`, they will show you `D` then `C` then `B` then `A`.

Patterns (with `--branches=*`) can be tricky, because command-line interpreters ("shells") tend to do their own expansion of `*`.  If you run `echo *` you will see a list of all of your file names.  If you run `echo foo*` you will see only file names beginning with `foo`.  `--branches=*` may attempt to expand to files whose names start with `--branches=`, especially if you have some files with those names.

If you omit the `*` at the end, Git supplies it internally, which avoids the shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response! I knew much of how git worked, but your explanation for `git rev-list` really helped steer me in the right direction. That, plus me better understanding `/refs`, helped me solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Is it a typo?:  instead of "git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-E>   # what happened on master " <= git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-F>